# see php version wrong in cmd and echo php

Tags: php, cmd, xampp

Php code (by echo phpversion() function ) and to view by the localhost/xampp  => Version 5.4 O appears but  in the CMD (commond Prompt) to view it appears 5.3.
what is problem ?

Comment: This may be because you installed two versions.

Comment: no, I didn't, install two versions.

Answer (score 0):

No problem..two installed versions. The CMD Env Path shows to another 
version as the Apache config.

Regards Bytecounter

Comment: okay, but I want only 5.4 version because I want install yii2.0, using CMD (command prompt ), it's only support 5.4 & high version of php.

Comment: So, remove the older version by the windows control panel and/or update the system environment path.